# How to view data on the Azure SQL database

Tags: sql, azure

I created a default ASP.NET web form web site using Visual Studio. By default it contains a `.mdf` database file, Registration page, Login page and some other pages. Then I host this web application on Azure as a web app.

After that I did several registrations for the web site and I need to see the data (data which i used on registration) on the hosted application.

Is there any way to connect to the database file in Azure? In Azure, I did not set up a connection string. I just publish the app and it manages the database connection itself.

Comment: in the azure portal you can browse to the database and see the connection string and then use it in sql management studio and view the db, tables etc

Comment: Thats what Im looking for but , There is nothing inside the "Database" section

Comment: it should be there if a database was successfully created. or check if you are looking into the correct subscription, resource group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is nothing inside the "Database" section

It seems that you do not publish your asp.net to Azure with Sql Database correctly. So, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase#publish-to-azure-with-sql-database) to check if you have deploy database correctly.

As you have published, you could go to the database on Azure portal and choose `query editor(preview)`. Click `Login` and enter the username and password you have set in `Azure Sql server`.
[image]

Also, you could open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to get your database. And you also need to login into the Sql Server as above.

[image]

After logining into the sql database, you will see all the data you have insert.

BTY, make sure you have synced the data in local database to Azure Sql Database. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync).